# How to fetch distinct year of datetype in Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 3 records of datatype in database and two of them have different year. My sql query is:  'SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(postdate) from post'.

in PostRepository.php I have such function:

```
<?php

namespace Dev\TaskBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql;

class PostRepository extends EntityRepository{
    public function getYears(){
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('YEAR(p.postdate')->distinct()
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

I had configured config.yml before and the error I receive is:

> Attempted to load class "Year" from namespace
>   "DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql". Did you forget a "use" statement for
>   another namespace?

Could someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: can you show your config.yml - your YEAR extension is not used

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to configure extension for `YEAR` function. You can do it via `config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. My URL in project is 'localhost:8000/web/app_dev.php/'       Am i in development environment then? Should I put that in config_dev.yml ? I posted my config.yml below and error keeps poping

Comment: in a standard setup config.yml is used by any stage and e.g. config_dev is then adding/replacing special requirements to the config.yml - if that's ok then you shouldn't have an issue with that point.

Comment: If this attempt didn't solve your problem can you say what error do you have now?